# How to block Win+G keyboard event

Tags: winapi

I am looking for a solution to block keyboard event for blocking Win + G combination to block windows game bar. I was able to disable windows key but not with the combination with G (Win+G windows gamebar in windows 10). It would be great if any one has came across this situation and found a solution for this to help me out.

I am using lowlevelkeyboardproc.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

Comment: You'll want to make sure that your uninstaller works well, because it's liable to be heavily used

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ROFL

Answer (score 3):

[How to turn the Game Bar on or off in Windows 10](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-3091550/turn-game-bar-windows.html):

> You can also disable the Game Bar using the registry.
>
> 1. **Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR**.
> 2. **Change the AppCaptureEnabled DWORD value to 0** to turn it off. Change it to 1 to turn it back on.
> 3. **Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore**.
> 4. **Change the GameDVR_Enabled DWORD value to 0** to turn it off. Change it to 1 to turn it back on.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want to disable programmatically though.

Comment: It is no problem to edit the registry programmatically using WinAPI.

Comment: I want to disable programmatically whenever my application is started on client machine using system hooks since it is not possible to change the settings on each client machine individually.

Comment: "I want to disable programmatically whenever my application is started on client machine" by changing the above mentioned values you can do exactly that and restore the origial settings once your application is about to quit.

Comment: Tried this and it is setting registry values successfully and I can see in logs but, still I am getting game bar If I press Win + G

Comment: This solution is working fine now, I was calling at incorrect location initially. thanks for the info.

Comment: @Swordfish-- I also need a way to block CAD(ctrl+alt+del) or taskmanager option. I am able to edit registry only if I run my program in administrator mode, but need to do it without admin permissions. my code for disable taskmanager option is ...

Comment: DWORD number = 0x00000001;
HKEY key;

if(RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE | KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &key) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
 errorLog("Key location open successful");
 if (RegSetValueExW(key, L"DisableTaskMgr", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&number, sizeof(DWORD)) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
  //success
 }else{
  //error
 }
 RegCloseKey(key);
} else {
 
 //unable to open
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will actually work (because I haven't explicitly tested it), but you could try snaffling this (or any other) key combination with [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx), e.g.

BOOL ok = RegisterHotKey (NULL, 1, MOD_WIN | MOD_NOREPEAT, 'G');

The call to `RegisterHotKey` will fail if some other app has already registered Win+G as a hotkey so you will just have to suck it and see, but if it *does* work then it is (clearly) better than hacking the registry.

See also [UnregisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646327.aspx).

Also there's (obviously) way too little information in the question.

Comment: Accept the answer then (but what happens if your app crashes before it can reinstate the original value?)

Comment: Resetting values back upon program exit and exception scenarios as well.

Comment: @Paul Sanders RAII is great!

Comment: @Swordfish I doubt anyone would disagree with you about that, but how is it relevant here?

Comment: @PaulSanders Just use a class's constructor and destructor to establish and revert the changes to the registry to make sure changes are left in place when an exception is thrown or the program ends.

Comment: @Swordfish I think you missed the point.  What happens if the program _crashes_ after twiddling the registry and therefore never gets round to putting it back as it was?